# Stuck at showing that we can partition a graph that has no odd cycles to a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have managed to reason that a bipartite graph can only have even length cycles with the definition of a cycle and the fact that crossing any edge $e \in V(G)$ results in a switch of partition class. But I am not sure how to show that when a connected graph $G = (V, E)$ does not have cycles of odd length, that we can construct the two partition classes $P_1, P_2 \subseteq V(G) s.t. P_1 \cup P_2 = V(G)$.

My initial ideal was to use coloring by choosing vertex $s$ to be any vertex of the maximal cycle $C$ in G and moving any subsequent vertex $t$ to either $P_1$ or $P_2$ depending on if the length from $s$ to $t$ is even or odd. But with this reasoning we cannot conclude that the two partitions would equal the original vertex set, $P_1 \cup P_2 = V(G)$, as we might not encounter every vertex in our maximal cycle. So how can I fix my proof?

Edit: It just occurred to me given the aforementioned vertex $t$, if $t$ has any neighbour $n$ s.t. $n \notin C$, we recursively iterate any such neighbour $n$ (and its neighbours $n': n' \notin C$) and move them to the appropriate set $P_1$ or $P_2$. What this would equal is more or less a proof with DFS algorithm. Can we conclude the proof with a more "mathematical" touch, so to say?

Comment: What's "the maximal cycle" in $G$? How do you know $G$ has any cycles at all?

Comment: Tou don't need a cycle. You've picked a root vertex $s$. Every vertex $v$ can be connected to $s$ by a path because $G$ is connected. Put $v$ in $P_1$ if there's an odd-length path from $v$ to $s$; put it in $P_2$ if there's an even-length path from $v$ to $s$.

Comment: For this to work you have to show that no vertex $v$ can be reached from $s$ in both an odd and an even number of steps. This amounts to showing that $G$ does not contain a closed walk of odd length. I assume that cycles and walks are defined so that cycles are *simple* (no self-intersections) while walks can cross and retrace themselves at will.

Comment: So what you have to show (unless you already know this) is that a graph which has a closed walk of odd length also has a (simple) cycle of odd length. Probably the way to do that is to assume you've got the shortest possible odd closed walk, and show that it must be a cycle. (Sorry for not being more definite but it's been years since I was in a graph theory class. Some stuff I remember pretty well, some not so much.)

Comment: @bof It had occurred to just fix a root vertex and depending on the length of the path so far assign vertices to either $P_1$ or $P_2$. Since G is connected, there does exist a spanning tree for G. But with this approach, how to we make sure that the two partition classes are real partitions, i.e. $\forall e \in E(G): e = {a, b}, a \in P_1, b \in P_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way to finish a proof is to construct sets for vertices that are even and odd distance away from a root vertex and reason whether or not it is possible that two elements from a same partition can share an edge.